# "Path" in graph theory: Can a vertex occur more than once?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I don't understand the definition of "path". The path is no vertex occur more than once. But this example use $a$ and $b$ twice.

> [image]

> [image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sources use slightly different definitions, just like $\mathbb{N}$ sometimes is defined to include $0$ and sometimes not. Nowadays paths generally don't allow repeated vertices, though we often still talk about Eulerian paths instead of Eulerian trails.

In your first book they use "simple paths" and "paths" instead of the currently more common "paths" and "walks".

Comment: yes,I understand , There is a mix of terminology. I also use two researces to check some terminology because sometimes the term is very complex and I don't understand .can ı accept which definition ?

Comment: @llee7jkonn The defnitions have changed over time. The table in your post is what is normally used now, and is what you probably should use when you write something. Just keep in mind that older (or old-fashioned) books and papers may use different ones.

Comment: thank you for advice.I take consider . Have nice day.

Comment: The term "elementary path" is also sometimes used for the case that vertices cannot be repeated.